# Ember 2.8: Unit testing for HTML5 audio tag playing

Tags: ember.js, qunit, ember-qunit, ember-testing

I'm writing some acceptance tests for my main route, and in my app some audio plays on load time. I would like to write up a test for this. This is what I'm thinking:

```
test('audio should be playing at startup', function(assert) {
  var isPaused = function () {
    return //some sort of indicator that audio is paused
  }
  visit('/');
  andThen(function () {
    assert.equal(isPaused(), false);
  })

})
```

I tried implementing something similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25750832/how-to-test-a-sound-is-playing), but it did not work for me. Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks.